# Laravel - How to redirect to previous url after email verification?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to redirect user to previous url after email verification.

Normally in Laravel 5.7 after you click on route which requires authentication you will be redirected back to that url after you log in.

I need same behaviour after e-mail verification.

Comment: You will have to store that url somewhere so you can restore it afterwards.

Comment: Not massively familiar with Laravel, but couldn't you just override it an auth controller?

Comment: What do you mean with previous url? The previous url will be likely the registration page.

Comment: I just found the way to change it. Added as an answer. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: If there is an easier way I am still open for suggestions.

Comment: `redirect()->back()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we need to modify **RedirectIfAuthenticated** and put intended url to session.

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if(session()->get("url.intended")){
            session()->put("redirect_after_email_verification", session()->get("url.intended"));
        }

        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/admin');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then add following code to **VerificationController** to check previously added url to session. If this url exist in session we will redirect user to that url after email verification.

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    return $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()
        ? redirect($this->redirectPath())
        : view('auth.verify');
}

protected function redirectTo(){
    if(session()->get("redirect_after_email_verification")){
        return session()->get("redirect_after_email_verification");
    }

    return $this->redirectTo;
}
```